# Getting AD user MemberOf (group memberships) values using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, get-aduser

I’m attempting to get MemberOf values for an AD user object. However, I’m hitting some roadblocks wherein I am not able to get an absolute list of AD group memberships (MemberOf) for a given AD user.

- I get most MemberOf AD Groups when I query `Get-ADUser` with `-Server` value set to the user object’s domain DC/GC
- Remaining, I’m only able to retrieve if I separately query for the same user object under the Root/Parent domain DC/GC

Below, based on my validation, I’ve jotted down the possible values for the PowerShell `Get-ADUser` cmdlet’s `-Server` parameter.

**PowerShell Get-ADUser “Server” parameter value options based on MemberOf Group’s Scope**

MemberOf a **Universal** group,

1. User domain DC/GC
2. Root/Parent domain GC
3. Other domains GC in the same forest

MemberOf a **Global** group,

1. User domain DC/GC

MemberOf a **Domain-local** group,

1. Group domain GC
2. Root/Parent domain GC

Now, my question goes, is my above deduction valid, and if yes is it by design - a thumb rule based on how the AD group memberships are designed to work?, or, is it more of a DC replication configuration thing?

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-security-groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of what you figured out is correct. A couple corrections/clarifications:

**Universal groups**

The `memberOf` attribute will always contain *all* universal groups that the user is a member of. This is because universal groups can only contain objects from the same forest, and you can only read the user from a DC/GC in the same forest. So you can be confident that you won't be missing any universal groups in `memberOf`.

**Global groups**

You're correct here. You'll only see global groups in `memberOf` if they are on the same domain as the user.

**Domain local**

This one is tricky. You will only see domain local groups in `memberOf` if they are on the same domain *as the server you are retrieving results from*.

Let's say your user is on DomainA. If you read from a GC in DomainB (that is in the same forest), then you will only see domain local groups in DomainB, and not DomainA.

This is why you do need to be careful if you're relying on `memberOf`. I discussed this in an article I wrote under the heading [*Beware of `memberOf`*](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/07/what-makes-a-member.html#beware-of-memberof)

How you approach this will depend on what your purpose is. This is something I discussed in another article I wrote on the topic, which might help you: [Active Directory: Finding all of a user’s groups](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/08/finding-all-of-a-users-groups.html)

Comment: Ah, saw this coming. Thanks Gabe! Fabulous write-ups on `memberOf`